# Docker-Compose Client API call to Server fails... default network service alias not working?

Tags: node.js, ajax, docker

I'm wondering how to fix this problem! Essentially the dynamic routing via service name on the default Docker network is not working. :(

I had considered making it use a static IP but that may be more work than fixing the original issue.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
    build: client
    ports: [3000]
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app

  mongodb:
    image : mongo
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports: [27017]
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/database:/data/db

  server:
    build: server
    ports: [5000]
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
```

If I do this ping test from the client it will work via the browser

```
http://0.0.0.0:49246/ping
```

However, I really want it to work in this approach here

```
http://server:5000/ping
```

Help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web app code runs in the browser, not the server hosting the files. The browser is typically running on the host.

It sounds like you want the server to map a known port on the host. Try using this to map host port 5000 to the `server` container port 5000...

```yaml
server:
  build: server
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  # etc
```

and connect on `http://localhost:5000` in your web app code.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

---

If you're wanting your web app to proxy requests (for example using the [Create React App `proxy` configuration](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)), you would use the internal host name since this action is performed by the `client` service.

```js
"proxy": "http://server:5000"
```

Comment: Aha the proxy runs inside the client service. Now that's a little gem there. I am wondering what is the difference between [5000] syntax and 5000:5000 for ports. I thought it was equivalent?

Comment: THANK YOU. Really thank you so much. array and string syntax for sure not the same xD

Comment: A single port on it's own exposes that container port on an ephemeral host port. See the documentation I linked